# Hide tap-highlight-color on ios 6.0.1

Tags: ios, mobile, hide, tap

Hide tap-highlight-color on ios 6.0.1

div {-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba (0,0,0,0);} does not work **anymore**
After upgrading to iOS 6.0.1 appeared to me a few errors in the Canvas 2d multiplayer game.
Also,
JS console is out , very bad !
simply do not believe in simulators.